How to parse JSON array that is converted into string in T-SQL
The inventory system I am using, has changed the way of storing the invoice lines and as you can see below the JSON array (Lines) has been converted into a string.
[
    {
        "TaskID": "06896b8d-770e-426f-ac82-000183252c47",
        "InvoiceNumber": "INV-9471D",
        "Lines": "[{\"ProductID\":\"a2540764-3e28-41f0-9ae8-c348a49ee941\",\"SKU\":\"BP13V1\",\"Name\":\"Biodynamic Whole Red Lentils 1kg\",\"Quantity\":1.0,\"Price\":11.95,\"Discount\":0.0,\"Tax\":0.0,\"Total\":11.95,\"AverageCost\":8.9882,\"TaxRule\":\"GST Free Income\",\"Account\":\"202\",\"ProductCustomField10\":\"\"},{\"ProductID\":\"aae9e53e-ad96-493c-99e3-1de193961fa8\",\"SKU\":\"BP6V1\",\"Name\":\"Organic Borlotti Beans 1kg\",\"Quantity\":1.0,\"Price\":9.25,\"Discount\":0.0,\"Tax\":0.0,\"Total\":9.25,\"AverageCost\":5.8832,\"TaxRule\":\"GST Free Income\",\"Account\":\"202\",\"ProductCustomField10\":\"\"}]",
        "TotalBeforeTax": 274.29,
        "Tax": 2.04,
        "Total": 276.33,
        "Paid": 276.33
    }
]

To parse the JSON lines, I created the following script that now returns a NULL instead of a specific value due too the change explained above:
SELECT
    dbo.Sale.[ID],
    [Invoices_Header].Inv_Number AS Doc_Num,
    [Invoices_Lines].[ProductID],                                           
    [Invoices_Lines].[QTY],
    [Invoices_Lines].[Price],
    [Invoices_Lines].[Discount],
    [Invoices_Lines].[Tax],
    [Invoices_Lines].[TaxRule],
    [Invoices_Lines].[Account]

FROM dbo.Sale

OUTER APPLY OPENJSON([Invoices], '$')
  WITH (
            Inv_Number VARCHAR(100)             '$.InvoiceNumber'

  ) AS [Invoices_Header]


OUTER APPLY OPENJSON([Invoices], '$.Lines')
  WITH (
            ProductID VARCHAR(100)      '$.ProductID',
            SKU VARCHAR(100)            '$.SKU',
            ProductName VARCHAR(100)    '$.Name',
            QTY DECIMAL (8,4)           '$.Quantity',
            Price NUMERIC(19,4)         '$.Price',
            Discount NUMERIC(5,2)       '$.Discount',
            Tax NUMERIC(19,4)           '$.Tax',
            Total NUMERIC(19,4)         '$.Total',
            TaxRule VARCHAR(100)        '$.TaxRule',
            Account VARCHAR(100)        '$.Account',
            AverageCost NUMERIC(19,4)   '$.AverageCost'

  ) AS [Invoices_Lines]

The final result should look like this:



ID
DOC_NUM
Product_ID
Qty
Price
Discount
Tax
Tax Rule
Account
Average Cost




06896B8D-770E-426F-AC82-000183252C47
INV-9471D
a2540764-3e28-41f0-9ae8-c348a49ee941
1
11.95
0
0
GST Free
202
8.97


06896B8D-770E-426F-AC82-000183252C47
INV-9471D
aae9e53e-ad96-493c-99e3-1de193961fa8
1
9.25
0
0
GST Free
202
7.5



Instead of this:



ID
DOC_NUM
Qty
Price
Discount
Tax
Tax Rule
Account
Average Cost




06896B8D-770E-426F-AC82-000183252C47
INV-9471D
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL


06896B8D-770E-426F-AC82-000183252C47
INV-9471D
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL



Is there a way of modifying the script above to properly parse the values from the JSON array that has been converted into a string?
Regards
David

Since the nested JSON is stored as a string in the outer JSON, the contained values cannot be accessed directly by parsing the Invoices column. Instead, you should add a '$.Lines' reference to the outer JSON column list, and then reference that column in the inner JSON using OPENJSON(Invoices_Header.Lines, '$')
This also properly handles any cases where the outer JSON contains more than one array element. The inner JSON reflects the Lines value for the current outer JSON element (matching the selected InvoiceNumber.
SELECT
    dbo.Sale.ID,
    Invoices_Header.Inv_Number AS Doc_Num,
    Invoices_Lines.ProductID,                                           
    Invoices_Lines.QTY,
    Invoices_Lines.Price,
    Invoices_Lines.Discount,
    Invoices_Lines.Tax,
    Invoices_Lines.TaxRule,
    Invoices_Lines.Account,
    Invoices_Lines.AverageCost  -- *** Added ***

FROM dbo.Sale

OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(Invoices, '$')
  WITH (
            Inv_Number VARCHAR(100)             '$.InvoiceNumber',
            Lines      NVARCHAR(MAX)            '$.Lines'  -- *** Added ***

  ) AS Invoices_Header

OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(Invoices_Header.Lines, '$')  -- *** Changed ***
  WITH (
            ProductID VARCHAR(100)      '$.ProductID',
            SKU VARCHAR(100)            '$.SKU',
            ProductName VARCHAR(100)    '$.Name',
            QTY DECIMAL (8,4)           '$.Quantity',
            Price NUMERIC(19,4)         '$.Price',
            Discount NUMERIC(5,2)       '$.Discount',
            Tax NUMERIC(19,4)           '$.Tax',
            Total NUMERIC(19,4)         '$.Total',
            TaxRule VARCHAR(100)        '$.TaxRule',
            Account VARCHAR(100)        '$.Account',
            AverageCost NUMERIC(19,4)   '$.AverageCost'

  ) AS Invoices_Lines

Note: If the nested JSON was exposed as just regular nested elements instead of as a quoted string value, we would use the AS JSON option when extracting the Lines content. Since the nested value is a string for this case, we do not use that option.
The missing AverageCost column reference has also been added to the final select list, and unnecessary name quoting has been removed to improve readability.
See this db<>fiddle for a demo.

You are the man. How can I offer you a beer? Could you suggest a book to learn more about this topic?

, '$' is not necessary as it's the default.
